# How to repeat the same string of text after a given symbol using a regular expression?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Please consider the following sample text:

**The work I have already manually done:**

```
data.put("difftnadh,difftnadh);

data.put("difftnafulltrans,difftnafulltrans);

data.put("difftnaparttrans,difftnaparttrans);

data.put("diffnotranstna,diffnotranstna);

data.put("difftradiradh,difftradiradh);
```

**The work that I have yet to go through:**

```
data.put("diffx401kdh,);

data.put("diffx401kfulltrans,);

data.put("diffroth401dh,);

data.put("diffroth401fulltrans,);

data.put("diffx403bdh,);
```

This is of course, not the entire data but just a fraction of the data I am showing here. As you can see, what I am doing is pretty simple. I am simply 
repeating the same string of text after each comma.

In a program like Notepad++ how would I instruct a regular expression to seek out a comma, take whatever the string is prior to that right up to the opening quotation mark and copy it over, right after the comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will surely help you out.

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kidnX8/2)

**Regex search:** `"([^,]+),`

**Replace:** `"$1,$1`

> **1.** `"([^,]+),` this will match `"` then match all except `,` and then `,` is matched. `()` will capture the first result in `$1`.

If you are using `gedit` `ubuntu`

> **Note:** If you are using gedit then, above `Replacement` pattern will not work for that you have to make replacement with `"\1,\1`

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `"([^",]+),` with `"$1,$1`.